# excel/google sheet - combining 2 column into 1 (vertically)

Tags: excel, row

what is the formula to combine 2 column into 1?

(sheet link included : [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15mP1q_Qia-CADqqn7mzbKwIS5YrGv4W4iqyUEpqfVWY/edit?usp=sharing))

for example :

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 |  |
| Cell 4 | Cell 5 |
| Cell 6 |  |

become :

| Combined | (with the spacing blanks included) |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 |  |
| Cell 3 |  |
| Cell 4 |  |
| Cell 6 |  |
|  |  |
| Cell 2 |  |
| Cell 5 |  |
|  |  |

this is the database primary sheet, so the plan is i will load/link from this database sheet to another sheet (plus in case i have another cell to add between, it will sorted out automatically)

i try arrayformula({A:A;B:B}) but it tells me to add another row ?

help please

formula tried :

- arrayformula,
- flatten,
  (it tells me to add another row?)
- unique
  (it overwrite the doubles? and remove blank space?, i need the text to be it as it is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following formula for raw materials. Then use same formula for packaging and change column references.

```
={FILTER(A:A,A:A<>"");" ";FILTER(E:E,E:E<>"")}
```

> Edit: To include blank cells try this formula-

```
={C1:INDEX(C1:C,MATCH("zzz",C1:C));" "; G1:INDEX(G1:G,MATCH("zzz",G1:G))}
```

Comment: hi thanks for quick solution, it worked well for the "rawmaterial" column, however the formula for "packaging" is not including the blank space

Comment: @ErsanRasubala does your example in your question show the difference between "packaging" and "rawmaterial"? if not, then you should improve your question.

Comment: sorry, it's in the sample sheet link

Comment: @ErsanRasubala Got your point. Try this formula `={C1:INDEX(C1:C,MATCH("zzz",C1:C));" "; G1:INDEX(G1:G,MATCH("zzz",G1:G))}`.